# Could this identity have an application?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$.

While trying to show another thing, I observed that $$C_G(C_G(C_G(H)))= C_G(H)$$

Does this identity have any application?

Answer (score 19):

I don't know about applications, but perhaps I can offer a bit of perspective.

> **Definition 0.** Let $P$ denote a poset. Then by an *orthomap* on $P$, I mean an order-**reversing** mapping $P \rightarrow P$
>   denoted $x \mapsto x^\perp$ satisfying either and therefore both of
>   the following.
>
> 1. $x^{\perp\perp} \geq x$
> 2. $x^\perp \geq y \iff x \leq y^\perp$.

*Exercise: show these are equivalent.*

> **Proposition.** Every orthomap satisfies $x^{\perp\perp\perp} \;= x^\perp.$

*Proof.* We know that LHS $\geq$ RHS, by substituting $x^\perp$ for $x$ in (1). On the other hand, we know that LHS $\leq$ RHS by applying the function $x \mapsto x^\perp$ to both sides of (1) and noting that it is order-reversing.

Orthomaps arise everywhere, in the following way. Suppose $X$ is a set and $R$ is symmetric relation on $X$. Then we get an orthomap $\mathcal{P}(X) \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(X)$ as follows. Given $A \subseteq X$, we define $A^\perp$ to be the unique subset of $X$ such that for all $x \in X$, the following are equivalent.

- $x \in A^\perp$
- for all $a \in A$, we have that $R(a,x)$.

*Exercise: show this is an orthomap.*

This gives many examples.

1. Suppose $X$ is a group, and let $R$ denote the binary relation on $X$ defined by $R(x,y) \iff xy=yx.$ Then $A^\perp$ is the centralizer of $A$.
2. Consider the case where $X$ is a commutative ring and $R$ is given by $R(x,y) \iff xy=0$. Then $A^\perp$ is the [annihilator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annihilator_%28ring_theory%29) of $A$.
3. Let $X$ denote an inner product space and suppose $R$ is given by $R(x,y) \iff \langle x,y\rangle = 0$. Then $A^\perp$ is the [orthogonal complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_complement) of $A$.

Interestingly, we always get a notion of "closure operator" from any orthomap. Let me be a little more precise:

> **Definition 1.** Let $P$ denote a poset. Then by a *closure operator* on $P$, I mean an order-**preserving** mapping $P \rightarrow P$
>   denoted $x \mapsto \mathrm{cl}(x)$ satisfying **both** of the following conditions.

1. $\mathrm{cl}(x) \geq x$
2. $\mathrm{cl}(\mathrm{cl}(x)) = \mathrm{cl}(x)$

*Exercise. Suppose $P$ is a poset equipped with an orthomap. Show that the function $\mathrm{cl} : P \rightarrow P$ defined by $\mathrm{cl}(x) = x^{\perp \perp}$ is a closure operator.*

> **Definition 2.** Suppose $P$ is a poset equipped with a closure operator. Then we call $k \in P$ *closed* iff one - and therefore all
>   three - of the following holds.
>
> 1. $k=\mathrm{cl}(p)$ for some $p \in P$.
> 2. $\mathrm{cl}(k) = k$.
> 3. $\mathrm{cl}(k) \leq k$.

In this enriched language, we can state our earlier proposition differently: it is just saying that $x^\perp$ is always closed.

Comment: really interesting. (+1)

Comment: @mesel, glad to be of service :)

Comment: glad to be serviced :)

Comment: Another example of an orthomap, this time from logic! Let $x \le y$ iff $x \rightarrow y$. Then $x \mapsto \neg x$ is an orthomap in both classical and intuitionistic logic, and indeed $x \le \neg y$ implies $y \le \neg x$, and also $\neg\neg\neg x = \neg x$, and this fact can be used to show that every first-order formula provable in classical logic can be translated into a formula provable in intuitionistic logic using double-negation translation (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-negation_translation). Does this count as an application? =)

Comment: Another example from fractional ideals: $((I^{-1})^{-1})^{-1}=I^{-1}$.

Comment: @user26857, sounds interesting, but I'm not quite sure what that notation means. Is it related to $(I:J)$ in the notation of [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_quotient) page?

Comment: It is $(R:I)$ from [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_ideal).

Comment: This is also interestingly related to [Galois connections](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_connection).