# What is the "unicital complement" really called, and which lowersets $\lambda$ satisfy $(\lambda^{\perp})^{\perp}= \lambda$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology, order-theory, filters

Whenever $P$ is a poset, write $L(P)$ for the collection of lowersets of $P$: $$L(P) := \{\lambda \subseteq P : \forall x,y \in P : x \leq y \,\&\, y \in \lambda \rightarrow x \in \lambda\}$$

With that notation in place, we can define "unicital complements" as follows, where $X$ is an arbitrary set:

$$L(\mathcal{P}(X)) \rightarrow L(\mathcal{P}(X)), \quad \lambda \mapsto \lambda^\perp$$ $$\lambda^\perp := \{x \in \mathcal{P}(X) : \forall y \in \lambda : |x \cap y| \leq 1\}.$$

In words: given a lowerset $\lambda$ of $\mathcal{P}(X)$, we get another lowerset $\lambda^\perp$ defined as the collection of all subsets of $X$ that intersect each element of $\lambda$ in at most one point. Call this the *unicital complement* of $\lambda$.

> **Mini Question.** What is the "unicital complement" of a collection of subsets really called, and has it been studied anywhere? (Please answer in the comments section.)

Remark 0. This is an [orthomap](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1219579/could-this-identity-have-an-application/1219622#1219622), or in other words an antitone Galois connection whose domain and codomain are identical.

Remark 1. If $P$ is a partially ordered set, then $\mathrm{Chain}(P)$ and $\mathrm{Antichain}(P)$ are unicital complements of each other.

> **Definition.** Call $\lambda$ unicital-closed iff $(\lambda^\perp)^\perp = \lambda$.

Remark 2. Not every lowerset satisfies $(\lambda^\perp)^\perp = \lambda$. For example, let $X$ denote a set and let $\lambda$ denote the empty subset of $X$. Then $\lambda^\perp$ is the collection of all subsets of $X$, and hence $(\lambda^\perp)^\perp$ is the collection of all subsets of $X$ with at most one element.

> **Main Question.** Given a set $X$, can we usefully characterize those lowersets $\lambda$ of $\mathcal{P}(X)$ that are unicital-closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\lambda$ be in $L(\mathcal P(X)$. Define $\lambda_2$ to be the set of all the members of $\lambda$ that have exactly two elements. Note that $\lambda^\bot$ consists of exactly those subsets $x$ of $X$ that have no subset in $\lambda_2$.

As a consequence, if $\mu$ is another element of $L(\mathcal P(X))$, then $\lambda^\bot=\mu^\bot$ if and only if $\lambda_2=\mu_2$. Recall the general property of Galois connections that $\lambda^{\bot\bot}$ is the largest element $\mu$ in the poset such that $\lambda^\bot=\mu^\bot$. So in our situation, $\lambda^{\bot\bot}$ is the largest $\mu$ in $L(\mathcal P(X))$ such that $\lambda_2=\mu_2$.

That $\mu$ is simply the collection of those $x\subseteq X$ such that all $2$-element subsets of $x$ are in $\lambda_2$.

With this description of $\lambda^{\bot\bot}$, we get that $\lambda$ is unicital-closed iff, whenever it contains all $2$-element subsets of some $x\subseteq X$, then it also contains $x$.

Such families $\lambda$ have shown up in various contexts and, as a result, have various names. In connection with linear logic, Girard called them coherence spaces. They are also called clique complexes in graph theory. (The point is that $\lambda_2$ is the set of edges of a simple graph with vertex set $X$, and $\lambda=\lambda^{\bot\bot}$ consists all the cliques of that graph.) I've also seen such $\lambda$'s called flag complexes, but I don't remember where.

On the other hand, I don't recall having seen a name for the ${}^\bot$ operation.